# Text files as my data set in dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, text-files

I am programming a webpage and using eclipse-jee-luna and applying dynamic web project for that. My data set is about 1000 txt files. Would you please tell me how I should include them in my project? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those will not get modified in runtime and Just for reading the data, you can create a jar file and keep it in WEB-INF/lib file(No need to add to Classpath in eclipse since they are just Text files and in run time Text files will pick from jar since it is in lib). You can access them using

```
 InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filePath in Jar");
```

If they are modifiable  you can keep them in WEB-INF/folder 
and access them using

```
   ServletContext context = getContext();
   InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/folder/filename");
```